# Keyboard Hide Textbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I'm doing an app and I want to create a page with Silverlight and XNA.
Normally when I create a textbox in a Silverlight page, when the textbox is focused the keyboard appears and the screen is auto-resized to allow user see the textbox while typing.
But in a silverlight page with XNA support as in this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28VS.92%29.aspx the screen isn't able to resize and sometimes the textbox is hidden by the keyboard.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to resize an xna game you use

`graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth`

and

`graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight`